# Stretch to fill row horizontally android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, tablerow

I'm probably missing something obvious here but I can't seem to figure this out. I am looking for a result like 1, 5, or 6, a single row of 3 evenly distributed buttons that fill the width of the screen. Unfortunately however, each of these methods seem to have something wrong with them. 1 gives me a warning that "This TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is possibly useless" and 5 and 6 give "Nested weights are bad for performance". So basically I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. Should I ignore the warning on no.1 or can I get them to display properly with just a TableRow or TableLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- No.1 -->
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tbRow0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num2" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num3" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<!-- No.2 -->
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tbRow1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num3" />
</TableRow>

<!-- No.3 -->
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tbRow2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn7" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn8" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn9" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num3" />
</TableRow>

<!-- No.4 -->
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tbRow3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn10" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn11" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn12" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num3" />
</TableRow>

<!-- No.5 -->
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tbRow4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn13" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn14" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num3" />
</TableRow>

<!-- No.6 -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn16" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn17" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn18" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num3" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- No.7 -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn19" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn20" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn21" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/num3" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think 5 is the correct one, plus I'm not getting the nested weights warning.

Maybe it's related to what Agarwal pointed.

**Edit:** sorry I though 5 was using a LinearLayout. What I mean is:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn13" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn14" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/num3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yah I only get that warning when I use it inside another LinearLayout for a ScrollView. I guess I'll just ignore that because I really don't know how much it can hurt.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file after first row you are closing tablelayout but even you are using table rows in 2 ,5 rows might be that a problem.

If you need it for only one then then better to have linearlayout because performance not to bad because you have a small xml file which is ok.

Comment: Yah I should have been more clear. I only want one row. I would use LinearLayout but "android:stretchColumns="*"" wont work for that so is there a similar attribute to use to distribute the buttons evenly through the row?

Comment: Edited my answer. Tell me if that is what you want!